# Food containing its reverse

Tags: riddle, word, english, letters

> When forwards,
>
> I am a type of food.
>
> When backwards,
>
> I am something contained within the food.

**What am I?**

Comment: If only [ragus](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/ragudipomodoro_70563) were a sweet dish ...

Comment: @Rand, I believe they often have brown sugar as an ingredient.

Comment: @Randal'Thor https://www.ragusa.ch/en/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps it is

> the Japanese food nori

which is

> iron backwards.

Comment: But nori does not have iron in it AFAIK

Comment: @matt According to wiki it does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nori#Nutrition

Comment: *facepalm* 4mtg

Answer (score 5):

It could be

> natas

Because

> They are so good they are evil.

Comment: Naras _are_ 'evil'. They don't _contain_ satan though.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is

> a **BUN** which can contain a **[NUB](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nub)**.